# Should I use sent token or user_id to get user's data

Tags: node.js, jwt

If an `user` have many `offers`, should I fetch them using sent Authorization `token` or send `user_id` separately in a body request?

I specified `Node.js` and `MongoDB` in case best practices differentiate from other tools.

Comment: I like to use the userId from token because its cleaner. Also, if you decide to use user_id from param, you should check that both are the same before returning the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think as you authenticate your user, you can store their user_id in the token payload.  Then as they make request, the token should come in the request header and you can use that to verify and get their user_id from the payload, then you can handle their request.

Comment: This is correct. You will also most likely want to store that JWT token in a cookie and then make it httponly and secure for security purposes.